# how to convert forEach to lambda

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
Iterator<Rate> rateIt = rates.iterator();
int lastRateOBP = 0;
while (rateIt.hasNext())
{
    Rate rate = rateIt.next();
    int currentOBP = rate.getPersonCount();
    if (currentOBP == lastRateOBP)
    {
        rateIt.remove();
        continue;
    }

    lastRateOBP = currentOBP;
}
```

how can i use above code convert to lambda by `stream` of java 8? such as list.stream().filter().....but i need to operation list.

Comment: are you trying to remove duplicates from the list?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc yep, i need to sort list, an then remove duplicates

Comment: @HavenLin the way you have it right now is not removing duplicates in the `entire list`; it's removing those that follow only. For example you have this `5,5,6,7,7,8,5` what is the expect result in this case? `5,6,7,8,5` or `5,6,7,8`

Comment: please look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670116/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-objects-based-on-property-in-java-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want distinct and sorted as you say in your comments, than it is as simple as :

```
TreeSet<Rate> sorted = rates.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> 
                   new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Rate::getPersonCount))));
```

But notice that in your example with an iterator you are not removing duplicates, but only duplicates that are *continuous* (I've exemplified that in the comment to your question).

**EDIT**

It seems that you want `distinct` by a `Function`; or in simpler words you want distinct elements by `personCount`, but in case of a clash you want to take the `max pos`.

Such a thing is not *yet* available in jdk. But it might be, see [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072723).

Since you want them sorted and distinct by key, we can emulate that with:

```
 Collection<Rate> sorted = rates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Rate::getPersonCount,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (left, right) -> {
                        return left.getLos() > right.getLos() ? left : right;
                    },
                    TreeMap::new))
            .values();

    System.out.println(sorted);
```

On the other hand if *you absolutely need* to return a `TreeSet` to actually denote that this are unique elements and sorted:

```
 TreeSet<Rate> sorted = rates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(

                    Collectors.toMap(Rate::getPersonCount,
                            Function.identity(),
                            (left, right) -> {
                                return left.getLos() > right.getLos() ? left : right;
                            },
                            TreeMap::new),
                    map -> {
                        TreeSet<Rate> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Rate::getPersonCount));
                        set.addAll(map.values());
                        return set;
                    }));
```

Comment: i used your code to test, but it has a bit difference.
Sample List as below:
`Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}`
**My expected**:
`Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}`,
**your code return**:
`Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}`

Comment: yes, my meaning is just as you said "in simpler words you want distinct elements by personCount, but in case of a clash you want to take the max Los",  but above code have expression error

Comment: @HavenLin it's impossible for me to tell what those errors are... plz provide them

Comment: sorry, it works well now~ this is my expected. thanks~

Comment: hi Engene, 
if i use `rates.stream().collect(groupingBy(Rate::getPersonCount))`, and then return Map<Integer, List<Rate>>, and result is `[[Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:1}, Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:2}, Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:3}], 
[Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}, Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:2}, Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:3}], 
[Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}], 
[Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}]]`, 
have there simple a way to get max LOS for each value in this map?

Comment: i post new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003534/how-can-i-get-value-from-list

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is

```
Set<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
rates.removeIf(rate -> !seen.add(rate.getPersonCount()));
```

it utilizes the fact that `Set.add` will return `false` if the value is already in the `Set`, i.e. has been already encountered. Since these are the elements you want to remove, all you have to do is negating it.

If keeping an arbitrary `Rate` instance for each group with the same person count is sufficient, there is no sorting needed for this solution.

Like with your original `Iterator`-based solution, it relies on the mutability of your original `Collection`.

Comment: I get back whatever I wrote before, this is very nice!

Comment: I agree with yours, it is the simplest and effectively answer when `Rate`s is in order.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your `Rate` type has *natural* ordering (i.e. implements `Comparable`):

```
List<Rate> l = rates.stream()
                             .distinct()
                             .sorted()
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If not, use a lambda as a custom comparator:

```
List<Rate> l = rates.stream()
                             .distinct()
                             .sorted( (r1,r2) -> ...some code to compare two rates... )
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It may be possible to remove the call to `sorted` if you just need to remove duplicates.

Comment: `compareTo` should be implemented in such a way that *same* `personCount` and *different* `los`  will report different entries (result will be `!=0`).  So the use of `distinct` will have no effect, it will still take all entries... What you want is distinct by a Function here