# how can i get value through complex logic from list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have filter `personCountFilter=3`, and have list as below:

```
Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:1, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:4}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:5}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:6}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:5, LOS:7}
Rate{ PersonCount:6, LOS:7}
```

After filter my expected:

```
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:4}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:5}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:6}
Rate{ PersonCount:5, LOS:7}
```

how can I get value after grouping by LOS, and if personCount matched filter get this one, if not matched, get closest to `personCountFilter`, bigger `personCountFilter` first

I tried to use

```
HashSet<Rate> testSet = rates.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toMap(Rate::getLengthOfStayCount,
                                Function.identity(),
                                (previous, current) ->
                                {
                                    return previous.getPersonCount() > 
                                           current.getPersonCount() ? previous : current;
                                }),
                        map ->
                        {
                            HashSet<Rate> set = new HashSet<>();
                            set.addAll(map.values());
                            return set;
                        }));
```

but it returns

```
Rate{ PersonCount:2, LOS:1}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:2}
Rate{ PersonCount:4, LOS:3}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:4}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:5}
Rate{ PersonCount:3, LOS:6}
Rate{ PersonCount:6, LOS:7}
```

Current it gets max personCount when after grouping by LOS

Comment: Could you make question more clear.. I dont understand what is expected : to be precise, I dont understand " and if personCount matched filter get this one, if not matched, get most near with personCountFilter, bigger personCountFilter first"

Comment: sos, help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178932/code-compiler-error-between-ide-language-level-7-and-8

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to test the following code with the information you have provided in the question (learn how to make a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your next question), but I think something like this should work for you:

```
HashSet<Rate> testSet = rates.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toMap(Rate::getLengthOfStayCount,
                        Function.identity(),
                        (previous, current) ->
                        {
                            int diff1 = Math.abs(personCountFilter - previous.getPersonCount());
                            int diff2 = Math.abs(personCountFilter - current.getPersonCount());
                            if (diff1 > diff2) {
                                return current;
                            } else if (diff1 < diff2) {
                                return previous;
                            } else if (diff1 == diff2) {
                                return previous.getPersonCount() <= current.getPersonCount() ? current : previous;
                            }
                        }),
                map -> new HashSet<>(map.values())
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the element of each group, which has the `personCount` property closest to the number `3`, with preference to the higher number in case of a tie.

You may achieve it using

```
HashSet<Rate> testSet = rates.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(Rate::getLengthOfStayCount,
                Function.identity(),
                BinaryOperator.minBy(
                   Comparator.comparingDouble(rate -> Math.abs(rate.getPersonCount()-3.1)))
        ),
        map -> new HashSet<>(map.values())
    ));
```

`Math.abs(rate.getPersonCount()-3)` is the distance to your goal number `3`, getting the element with the minimum of that value will get the closest. By simply using `3.1` instead of `3`, we achieve preference to higher numbers in case of a tie (assuming that you property has an integer type).