# Code compiler error between IDE language level 7 and 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
List<Restriction> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
//list operation.......
when(restrictionUpdator.executeBatch(anyInt(), 
                                     any(List.class), 
                                     any(RequestorInfo.class),
                                     (Class<Obj>) any())
     ).thenReturn(restrictions);
```

**excuteBatch method:**

```
public <T extends Obj> List<T> executeBatch(int Id, 
                                                List<UpdateContext> contexts,
                                                RequestorInfo requestor, 
                                                Class<T> tClass)
```

**Class:**

```
public class Restriction extends Obj
```

Can someone have a look? 
Why above code has compiler error in IDE language 8?
If I change IDE language 8 to 7, it is back to normal and build success.

Comment: **WHICH** error?

Comment: @JBNizet Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(java.util.List<Restriction>)'

Comment: Well, the last argument, declared as Class<T>, is of type Class<ICPRObj>. So executeBatch is supposed to return a List<T>, i.e. a List<ICPRObj>. But you make it return a List<Restriction>.

Comment: @JBNizet Restriction extend Obj, why should be not return List<Restriction>? it works well in language level 7

Comment: Now you've changed your code... So my previous explanation doesn't stand anymore. But the explanation for the new code is the same: your method is supposed to return a List<Obj>, since you're passing a Class<Obj>, and the generic type T is thus inferred as Obj. A List<Restriction> is NOT a List<Obj>.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information.

Comment: what about replacing ` (Class<Obj>) any())` by `any(Class.class). Even if it would compile (e.g. by changing it to `(Class<Restriction>) any()`, it would not run in the old way.

Comment: @CoronA finally, i used (Class<Restriction>) any()